# Парсинг таблицы с сайта java

Tags: java, парсер

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт с проксями, надо спарсить оттуда две колонки. Прокси и номер порта с которым она работает.
Вот таблица сайта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код на *Java*. В чем ошибка?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://proxy-besplatno.com/").get();

    for (Element table : doc.select("table.tb1")) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr.tr_index")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            if (tds.size() > 1) {
                System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + ":" + tds.get(1).text());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `В чем ошибка?` - для начала скажите а что не так?

Comment: программа выполняется, но ничего не выводит.

Comment: у тебя `tb1` вместо `tbl` ;-)  ......... сразу скажу что порт не парсится потому что там картинка а не текст

Comment: Ух как стыдно(. Весь день мучаюсь, ерундовое задание, ошибку не мог найти, хоть тресни. Да, все работает. Спасибо!